# Empty time blocks with groupby TimeGrouper on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
time,name,status
2016-10-09 00:15:50,10.0.0.24,REJECTED
2016-10-09 00:15:50,10.0.0.24,REJECTED
2016-10-09 00:15:54,10.0.0.24,accepted
```

Which is grouped using this code

```
dfx = df.set_index(['time'])
dfx = dfx[dfx.status == 'accepted']
grouper = dfx.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("20min"), 'name'])
dfTime = grouper['name'].count().unstack('name').fillna(0)
```

Giving a dataframe detailing event counts per IP address that looks something like this:

```
time,10.0.0.103,10.0.0.24
2016-10-11 20:20:00,8,6
2016-10-11 20:40:00,151,198
2016-10-11 21:00:00,150,209
2016-10-11 21:20:00,136,214
2016-10-11 21:40:00,155,196
2016-10-11 22:00:00,140,218
2016-10-11 22:20:00,170,219
2016-10-11 22:40:00,154,193
2016-10-11 23:00:00,141,195
2016-10-11 23:20:00,149,206
2016-10-11 23:40:00,132,190
2016-10-12 00:00:00,140,197
2016-10-12 00:20:00,182,238
2016-10-12 00:40:00,171,215
2016-10-12 01:00:00,40,45
2016-10-12 12:40:00,100,196
2016-10-12 13:00:00,171,212
2016-10-12 13:20:00,180,200
2016-10-12 13:40:00,184,220
```

You will note that where there was no data (between 00:40 and 01:00, for instance) there is simply no grouping completed. I need each 20 minute block to be represented in the final data frame with 0 counts for the respective IPs, i.e.:

```
2016-10-12 00:40:00,171,215
2016-10-12 00:50:00,0,0
2016-10-12 01:00:00,40,45
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: what about using `resample()` instead of `groupby()`?